# Как редактировать изображение, полученное с блока img, и вставить только его часть или как убрать рамки у изображения?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Есть ли возможность убрать рамки у изображения, полученного через `background-image`? Варианты: `border: 0; border-style: none; outline: 0; outline-style: none;` - не работают.

Есть, конечно, возможность получить изображение, используя атрибут `src=".../smile.png"`, но тогда возникает проблема с получением конкретной части изображения.
Дело в том, что при загрузке изображения через первый вариант, у меня дополнительно устанавливаются координаты конкретной части изображения, а эти настройки CSS не работают, когда получаешь изображение через атрибут ***src***.

Возможно ли передать установленные координаты, используя более корректный метод получения изображения (я имею ввиду через ***src***)?

Первый вариант кода с рамками на выходе:

```html
<span aria-label=", +1, thumbsup" class="emoji-mart-emoji">
<span style="
   display: inline-block; 
   width: 24px; height: 24px; 
   background-image: url(&quot;https://unpkg.com/emoji-datasource-apple@5.0.1/img/apple/sheets- 
             256/64.png&quot;); 
   background-size: 5700% 5700%; 
   background-position: 23.2143% 67.8571%;
"></span></span>
```

Второй вариант через src, но тогда я получаю все изображение целиком:

```html
<img 
  src="https://unpkg.com/emoji-datasource-apple@5.0.1/img/apple/sheets-256/64.png" 
  style="
    width: 24px; 
    height: 24px; 

    # следующие два параметра являются теми координатам, которые нужно получить в заданном масштабе

    background-size: 5700% 5700%; background-position: 53.5714% 73.2143%;
">
```

Comment: не вижу в коде border... можете добавить код в виджете чтоб его можно было открыть?

Answer (score 0):

1. Оформите код как положено в виде сниппета, чтобы выполнялся.
2. Вот я воспроизвел кусок вашего кода. Там все нормально, не вижу никаких бордеров. И их не должно быть, если не задавать специально.

Сформулируйте вашу задачу точнее, приведите полный код и покажите скриншот.

```css
.inner {
display: inline-block; 
   width: 24px; height: 24px; 
   background-image: url('https://unpkg.com/emoji-datasource-apple@5.0.1/img/apple/sheets-256/64.png'); 
   background-size: 5700% 5700%; 
   background-position: 23.2143% 67.8571%;
}
```

```html
<span aria-label="" class="emoji-mart-emoji">
<span class="inner"></span></span>
```

Comment: Я ошибся, первый вариант верный с использованием span, мне нужно передать это изображение через img, и тогда появляются границы. '<img style="display: inline-block; 
   width: 24px; height: 24px; 
   background-image: url('https://unpkg.com/emoji-datasource-apple@5.0.1/img/apple/sheets-256/64.png'); 
   background-size: 5700% 5700%; 
   background-position: 23.2143% 67.8571%;">'. При таком подходе получаются границы которые не убрать. @mego4iter

Comment: вот и спрашивал поэтому ваш полный код (добавьте в вопрос), ибо понять не могу откуда в принципе у картинки берутся границы - она ж с прозрачным фоном. И зачем тегу <img> делать еще и фон с ним же?

Answer (score 0):

Что я имею ввиду под границами при передаваемом изображении через ***style="background-image: url(../smile.png)"***, которые нужно убрать.

```html
<img style="display: inline-block; width: 24px; height: 24px; background-image: url(&quot;https://unpkg.com/emoji-datasource-apple@5.0.1/img/apple/sheets-256/64.png&quot;); background-size: 5700% 5700%; background-position: 23.2143% 67.8571%;">
```

Comment: да нет там никаких границ.

Comment: Рамка серая вокруг смайла.

Comment: Понял.

Так будет всегда, если src пустой или картинка не подгрузилась. Это браузерная рамка, отключается в настройках. Я-то думал, у вас бордер откуда-то именно в стилях/хтмл возникает...

Comment: Понятно, а я думал это как раз рамка из стилей возникает))